# HtmlUnit - Connection through proxy : URLConnection OK, WebClient KO

Tags: htmlunit

I cannot access http pages through a proxy with WebClient.

When I use an URLConnection there is no problem :

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("hostname", 8080));

URLConnection urlConnection = new URL("https://www.google.com/").openConnection(proxy);

BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

try {

    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        System.out.println(line);
    }

} finally {

    if (bufferedReader != null) {

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

But when I try with WebClient, I have an error :

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME, "hostname", 8080);

webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage("https://www.google.com/");

System.out.println(htmlPage.asText());
```

The error is "407 Proxy Authentication Required. The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied."

I don't understand why with URLConnection there is no authentication problem.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you looked at your Browser settings on your system?

Comment: @Paul Bastide : I am not sur to understand, HtmlUnit doesn't use system's browser, it simulates a browser. I have tried to change WebClient options but I always have the same error.

Comment: 407 is generally related to a system setting for proxy authentication, therefore I would check to see if you have an autodetect in your browser, if you do, I would then see what you can do to override it in your webclient code